# what's the difference between ios_base::ate and ios_base::trunc?

Tags: c++, windows

Here is the documents from MSDN:
**ate**, to seek to the end of a stream when its controlling object is first created.

**trunc**, to delete contents of an existing file when its controlling object is created.

I just can't understand the differences between them, the following two code snippet behave the same(they clear the contents before doing insert), anyone can help me find out the differences?

code snippet 1:

```
ofstream ofs(L"F:\\iMoney.txt", ios_base::trunc);
ofs << L"Hello, money~" << endl;
ofs.close();
```

code snippet 2:

```
ofstream ofs(L"F:\\iMoney.txt", ios_base::ate);
ofs << L"Hello, money~" << endl;
ofs.close();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For `std::ate` to make real sense, you need to open an `fstream` for both reading and writing:

```
std::fstream file("iMoney.txt", std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::ate);
```

This will preserve existing content, and the write position will start out at the end of the file, so what you write will be appended to the existing content unless you use `seekp` to move the write position somewhere else.

By contrast, if you specify `std::ios::trunc`, all existing content will be removed from the file (regardless of specifying `std::ios::in`, `std::ios::out`, or both). But if you just specify `std::ios::out`, which the default for an `std::ofstream`) all the existing content will be removed anyway. The only time `std::ios::trunc` adds anything useful is what you also specify both `in` and `out`, in which case the existing content *would* be preserved if you didn't specify `std::ios::trunc`.

Answer (score 0):

Your example doesn't make much of a difference if the file is empty or new, but if the file already contained characters then opening with `std::ios_base::ate` and writing to the file will *append* characters while writing after opening with `std::ios_base::trunc` will *overwrite* those characters.

Comment: no, my file is not empty. ios_base::ate will clear the contents at first, then do insert.